# Two Decimal places using c#

Tags: c#, formatting

```
decimal Debitvalue = 1156.547m;

decimal DEBITAMT = Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:0.00}", Debitvalue));
```

I have to get only two decimal places but by using this code I am getting 1156.547.
Which format do I have to use to display two decimal places?

Comment: Math.Round would work and even your code would work. I tested with your code and it worked fine
decimal Debitvalue = Convert.ToDecimal("1156.547");

            decimal DEBITAMT = Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:0.00}", Debitvalue));

            Console.WriteLine(DEBITAMT);

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want to round the decimal, look at `Math.Round()`

Comment: why not this Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:F2}", Debitvalue));, when we are already using convert.todecimal in code.

Comment: @Dragon - because converting a number to a string and back to a number is a code-smell.

Comment: ooh kk..then i will use like this Math.round(Convert.todecimal(val),2)..

Answer (score 82):

Your question is asking to display two decimal places. Using the following String.format will help:

```
String.Format("{0:.##}", Debitvalue)
```

this will display then number with up to two decimal places(e.g. 2.10 would be shown as 2.1 ).

Use  "{0:.00}", if you want  always show two decimal places(e.g. 2.10 would be shown as 2.10 )

Or if you want the currency symbol displayed use the following:

```
String.Format("{0:C}", Debitvalue)
```

Comment: Actually, the format in the first one would be "{0:.00}", if he wanted 2.10 to show. With ##'s it would be 2.1.

Comment: this one is not really working. it will round 4.998 to 5 but OP wants to have 2 decimals as 4.99

Comment: you can also write this `String.Format("{0:C}", Debitvalue)` as `$"{Debitvalue:C}"`

Answer (score 63):

Use [`Math.Round()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as4h66hd) for rounding to two decimal places

```
decimal DEBITAMT = Math.Round(1156.547m, 2);
```

Answer (score 43):

The best approach if you want to ALWAYS show two decimal places (even if your number only has one decimal place) is to use

```
yournumber.ToString("0.00");
```

Comment: Why is it the best approach?

Answer (score 22):

**I use**

```
decimal Debitvalue = 1156.547m;
decimal DEBITAMT = Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:F2}", Debitvalue));
```

Answer (score 17):

here is another approach

```
decimal decimalRounded = Decimal.Parse(Debitvalue.ToString("0.00"));
```

Answer (score 12):

For only to display, property of `String` can be used as following..

```
double value = 123.456789;
String.Format("{0:0.00}", value);
```

Using `System.Math.Round`. This value can be assigned to others or manipulated as required..

```
double value = 123.456789;
System.Math.Round(value, 2);
```

Answer (score 7):

Another way :

```
decimal.Round(decimalvalue, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably a variant of the other examples, but I use this method to also make sure a dot is shown before the decimal places and not a comma:

```
someValue.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the [Decimal.Round Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.round%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If someone looking for a way to display decimal places even if it ends with **".00"**, use this:

```
String.Format("{0:n1}", value)
```

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-numeric-n-format-specifier

Comment: I think this is best for my application. It guarantees showing 2dp and handles the local decimal separator.

Answer (score 1):

To display two decimal digits, try the given syntax.

string.Format("{0:0.00}", Debitvalue)

Answer (score 0):

```
double doubleNumber= 1.1; // 7.25 // 700.0
string uptwoDecimalPlaces= number.ToString("F2");
```

Answer (score -1):

In some tests here, it worked perfectly this way:

```
Decimal.Round(value, 2);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: What does this add to, say, [Kabilan Smart's 2015/02 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28362196)?