# How can I get no more and no less than two decimal places in a decimal value?

Tags: c#, excel, decimal, excel-interop, decimal-precision

With this code:

```
totalPriceCell.Value2 = TotalPrice;
```

...I was getting values such as "3.14963245" which I want to be "3.15" instead.

So I used this code:

```
totalPriceCell.Value2 = TotalPrice.ToString("#.##");
```

...and that did solve *that* problem, but I still get values such as "7.6" and "35" (which I want to be "7.60" and "35.00")

What can I do to accomplish this, outside of manually appending a "0" for vals such as "7.6" and manually appending ".00" for values such as "35"?

### UPDATE

Niether suggestion worked, neither this:

```
totalPriceCell.Value2 = TotalPrice.ToString("F2");
```

...nor this:

```
totalPriceCell.Value2 = Math.Round(TotalPrice, 2).ToString("F2");
```

I still get "7.6" etc.:

### UPDATE 2

It turns out to be an Excel problem, because when I added this:

```
MessageBox.Show(Math.Round(TotalPrice, 2).ToString("F2"));
```

...I did see values such as "7.60" (not "7.6").

[image]

Comment: Member for more than 5 years and still asking poor, research lacking  questions...

Comment: So, you want to round your value to 2 decimal places? Why not just use the `Math.Round(value, 2)` function and then `.ToString("F2")` that?

Comment: Take a look at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749506/two-decimal-places-using-c-sharp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to round the numbers to 2 decimal places, and *then* output the answer with trailing 0.

Just use the `Math.Round()` function to round, and then display using the `.ToString("F2")` format:

```
totalPriceCell.Value2 = Math.Round(TotalPrice, 2).ToString("F2");
```

---

`Math.Round(arg1, arg2)`: Where 1st argument *(arg1)* is the value you want to round, and 2nd argument *(arg2)* is the decimal places you wish to round to.

`.ToString("F2")`: Usage of `"F2"` - *F* being the "fixed-point" format specified; *2* being the number of digits after the decimal point.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm still having the problem, but it's apparently an Excel display problem.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon -- Ah, right - sorry to hear that - good ol' Excel. Wasn't 100% clear that you were using Excel, from your original question, until you've just updated it. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the #.00 format instead.

Comment: You can; but from what I can tell the OP is looking to also round the numbers, too

Answer (score 0):

Because it's Excel, I had to tell the range/cell exactly how to behave, like so:

```
totalPriceCell.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00";
```