# Number Format in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to formatting decimal number in c#.I tried ToString("N") and String.Format but it does not work because Total is defined as a decimal in the database.For example, If the total is 93.7567, then it should be 93.76. Here is the code:

```
   Total = g.Sum(c => c.Total)
```

Comment: do you want to display total with 2 decimals, or do you want to round total to two decimal places?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749506/two-decimal-places-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You could use Math.Round() Method.

```
total = Math.Round(total,2); // 93.7567 becomes 93.76.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try    decimalvalue.ToString("#.##"); or decimalvalue.ToString("F")