# How do I dynamically auto format a number with 2 decimals (.00) using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I've a requirement on Regex like below for U.S. Currency (without ,).

If the user enter amount in TextBox (HTML) control then it should Auto format with below expected format.

If value is 1111 - then Auto format with 1111.00

If value is 1111.0 - then Auto format with 1111.00

If value is 1111.00 - then Auto format with 1111.00

I tried like below and it is not working.

```
([0-9]*)[ (.00)]?
```

Format: **$1.00**

Any suggestion please

EDIT:

In C#

```
   Regex validate = new Regex("([0-9]*)[ (.00)]?");
   if (validate.IsMatch(1111))
   {
     console.writeline(validate.Replace(1111, "$1.00"));
   }
```

Comment: TextBox in what context? HTML5 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two Decimal places using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749506/two-decimal-places-using-c-sharp) - not sure why you want to format using regex, makes code less maintainable

Comment: @ctwheels, Please see tags. I didn't ask in C#

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi you mentioned **C#** in your previous comment (which you've since *conveniently* deleted)

Comment: @ctwheels, People like you will get smart answers.. that'y i've removed C#.  What i mean C# is.. please see my updated question.

Comment: I gave a viable answer according to all the information I had at the time. One of those pieces of information just so happened to be the language you are using (C#) which your - now deleted - comment specified. Regex cannot be used to edit strings, it is used to validate/search a string for *something*. If you're looking to validate a number using regex, there are many existing stackoverflow questions that offer a solution for that. If you are looking to format your number, the only way to do so is not using regex, in which case the **ONLY** viable answer is to use your project's langauge - C#

Comment: @ctwheels, Not sure what you are saying... in my C# example above.. replace below values then 1111 will become 1111.00. (\d+) and $1.00

Comment: RegEx is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: What if they input `1111.1`?

Comment: This `([0-9]*)[ (.00)]?` matches everything because it can match nothing. It is unclear as to what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not based on a regex all along but it workable and probably will give you ideas

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("1111");
            list.Add("1111.0");
            list.Add("1111.10");
            foreach (string num in list)
            {

                Regex re = new Regex("([0-9]+)(?:\\.)?(\\d)?(\\d)?");
                Match match = re.Match(num);

                Console.WriteLine();
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value + "." + match.Groups[2].Value.PadRight(1,'0') + match.Groups[3].Value.PadRight(1, '0'));
                }
            }
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
```

speaking about your code, the regex could be like this:

```
Regex validate = new Regex("([0-9]+)(?=\\.\\d{0,2})?");
            if (validate.IsMatch("1111"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(validate.Replace("1111", "$1.00"));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var li = new List<string>()
        {
            "1111", "3333.0", "1111.00", "9999.4",
        };

        string MoneyDecimals(string num)
        {
            var rx1 = new Regex(@"\.\d$");
            var rx2 = new Regex(@"^\d+$");

            if (rx1.IsMatch(num))
                return num + "0";
            else if (rx2.IsMatch(num))
                return num + ".00";
            else
                return num;
        }

        foreach (var item in li)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MoneyDecimals(item));
        }

        //1111.00
        //3333.00
        //1111.00
        //9999.40
```